# React: Using State Variable In Image Src?

Tags: reactjs, image

So I've exported all of the images in my image folder by using an index.js inside the same folder and writing exports such as `export const Image = require("./image.png");`. I then imported said images into my React app with `import { Image, Image2, Image3 } from from "./imageFolder";`

When I use the imported images as src values in my image tags, they work just fine so I know I've properly imported my image. The big issue that I have though is I've been trying to utilize the value of a state variable in the file to dynamically render a different image based on the state. The state variable's values are varied due to its values deriving from a database request that's stored in a state array.

```
{
  Object.keys(this.state.videos).map((video, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
      <p>Event: {this.state.videos[video].eventName}</p>
      <p>P1 Character: {this.state.videos[video].p1Character}</p>
      <p>P2 Character: {this.state.videos[video].p2Character}</p>
      </div>
      );
      })
}
```

Say that in this instance, the value of `{this.state.videos[video].p1Character}` is equal to "Image" - which corresponds with the name of the image I imported above. So why can't I do `<img src={this.state.videos[video].p1Character} />`? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it becaue the `p1Character` is a string and not a live variable.

You could however import the images as

```
import * as Images from from "./imageFolder";
```

and then use the `p1Character` to reference the image in the `Images`.

```
<img src={Images[this.state.videos[video].p1Character]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't understand what you mean, I don't see how it would be possible to have this `this.state.videos[video].p1Character` equal to `Image/Image2/Image3` if you have just save a reference to them as a string because you are literally just going to be writing `src="Image/2/3"`.

The best thing to do would to be store a unique key string for the images on a record and then just have a simple object map in your component like

```
const myImageMap = {
  image1: Image,
  image2: Image2,
  image3: Image3
}

/////
///// somewhere in your render
/////

<img src={myImageMap[this.state.videos[video].p1Character]} />
```

They key is that we are mapping to the strings to actual imported images